# How to display above the card Component image

Tags: react-native

I want to disply some discount offer on my card camponent above the image of card in ReactNative. What we call this feature. I am going to attach sample image for better under standing.[image]

Comment: Please show your coding efforts as well along with the image.

Comment: Sure Singh, I will.. whenever i need to fix the code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it by absolute positioning. Please refer this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@sivakumar00/absolute_positioning). Make you image as **ImageBackground** component. Then use other component inside it.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '50%',
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            padding: 20,
          }}
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522057306606-8d84daa75e87?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80',
          }}>
          {/** top-right corner */}
          <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0 }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 20,
                color: 'black',
                backgroundColor: 'white',
              }}>
              35 mins
            </Text>
          </View>
          {/** top -left */}
          <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 10, left: 0 }}>
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 20, color: 'white', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
              Flat 50%
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 40, left: 0 }}>
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 20, color: 'white', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
              Free delivery
            </Text>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you know what is specific term we use for that ?

Comment: we can say it as overlay, z-index, absolute positioning

Comment: I cant able to use imagebackground in the card

Comment: You can create a card using View component, there is no need for separate card component. This approach should work on all component. Check it once again. if not solved. you can post it as question